# Generic container in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic container to which I can pass any data and extract it later with the compiler keeping track of the classes.

Example:

```
Container a = new Container(0.3);
a.getValue();// returns 0.3 of type double
Container b = new Container("OMG");
b.getValue();// returns "OMG" of type String
```

I have no restrictions on how to do it. I was thinking of something like this.

```
public class GameSetting {
    Object value;
    Class valueClass;

    public GameSetting(Object value, Class valueClass) {
        this.value = value;
        this.valueClass = valueClass;
    }

    public Class<?> getValue() {
        return (valueClass)value;
    }
    public Class getClass(){return this.valueClass;}
}
```

but I get **unknown class:'valueClass'** error.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: you should probably first read the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html . The error is due to the fact that `valueClass` is a variable, not a `Class` (note the difference between "Object of type java.lang.Class" and "Class").

Comment: what is Class `valueClass` ?...Class is a reserved keyword in java.You can't use it as class/variable/method names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Your basic container class will look something like this...

```
public class Container<T> {
    private final T value;

    public Container(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You then use it like this...

```
Container<Double> a = new Container<>(0.3);
a.getValue();// returns 0.3 of type double
Container<String> b = new Container<>("OMG");
b.getValue();
```

One thing to beware of with generics is that they don't work directly with Java primitive types - so if you're going to use them with `int` and `double` you need to understand Java's [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) feature.

Comment: Yeah. This is what I ended up doing after reading more about generics. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class<?> getValue() {
        return (Class) (value);
    }
```

You are trying to type cast with the references instead of Class. Also you shouldn't override the final method getClass().